# Is It Possible To Write Webhook Code From Shopify Theme Extension App?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-cli, shopify-app-extension

Can we able to write a web-hook code inside the theme extension app without the Shopify server app?

If any possibilities kindly update here which will be helpful for me.

Possibilities to write webhook code and need to trigger when order Fulfilment event occurred